# Can === hold when == doesn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any cases where

```
x == y //false
x === y //true
```

is that ever possible in JS? :)

Comment: I wouldnt think so. But then again, javascript is never short of surprises

Comment: if the first line changed `x` or `y` (using a mutating getter or even an overloaded valueOf), then it could happen, but on it's face, no.

Comment: the most illustrative and educational way to see that it is not possible is to look at this table https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'd be impossible. `==` compares value, while `===` compares value and type. Your case would require an impossible condition.

```
a === b -> (typeof(a) == typeof(b)) && (value(a) == value(b))
a == b ->  (value(a) == value(b))
```

You couldn't have the value comparisons in the `==` case be true while requiring the exact same comparison in `===` become false.

Answer (score 10):

No. That's never possible. `===` checks for type and equality. `==` just checks for equality. If something isn't `==` it can never be `===`.

Answer (score 3):

[`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) - Returns true if the operands are equal.

[`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) - Returns true if the operands are equal and of the same type.

So, I'll say *not possible.*

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, if `===` is true, then `==` will return true.  If `===` returns false, then `==` may or may not return false.

Examples:

`5===5` is true, which means that `5==5` also must be true.

`'5'===5` is false, and `'5'==5` is true.

`'6'===5` is false, and `'6'==5` is also false.

This behavior is because `a===b` checks to make sure that the value and type of `a` and `b` are equal, while `a==b` only checks to make sure that their values are equal.